# Copy files from CSV to existing Excel in Powershell

Tags: excel, csv, copy, paste, powershell-4.0

I have a CSV file with some data. For example:

```
         CSV                ------>            EXCEL
    Name,Address,Phone                  Name,Address,Phone
    Nick,aaa,9990008989                 Nick,aaa,NULL
    Josh,bbb,8889990909                 Josh,bbb,NULL
```

I would like to copy each phone number to that specific name from my csv file to the excel one. How would that be possible in powershell? Thank you

Comment: I think you should use an excel macro to import data from CSV instead of running Powershell, because Powershell would have to use Excel to open Excel's files. So why wrapping Excel in Powershell, if you can do the same via Excel only?

Comment: @Vesper I am using a powershell script that opens the csv file and uses the data!